# Bounded generation of group by unipotent radicals of opposite parabolic subgroups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an almost $k$-simple group that is also simply connected (so that $G(k)^{+}=G(k)$). For opposite parabolic subgroups $P$ and $P^{-}$, it is known that $G(k)^{+}$ is generated by the unipotent radicals $R_u(P)(k)$ and $R_u(P^{-})(k)$ (Prop 1.5.4 in Margulis's book "Discrete Subgroups of Semisimple Lie groups).

Can this generation be extended to bounded generation? That is, is $G(k)=G(k)^{+}$ boundedly generated by $R_u(P)(k)$ and $R_u(P^{-})(k)$?

Comment: What does "bounded generation" / "boundedly generated" mean?

Comment: (Also, your $P$ and $P^-$ must not contain any simple factor of $G$.)

Comment: @LSpice: Bounded generation, in this case, would mean that there exists some constant $N$ such that any element $g \in G$ is of the form $g=a_1b_1a_2b_2\dots a_Nb_N$ where $a_i \in R_u(P)$ and $b_i \in R_u(P^{-})$. It is a strengthening of generation by insisting that lengths are bounded globally.

Comment: You need $G$ to be $k$-isotropic. If $G$ is $k$-anisotropic, this is clearly false.

Comment: If generation holds for every field (over which $G$ is $k$-isotropic), then bounded generation should also hold, by a simple ultraproduct argument.

Comment: @YCor, would you be willing to outline [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430665/bounded-generation-of-group-by-unipotent-radicals-of-opposite-parabolic-subgroup#comment1108196_430665) argument?  I can certainly believe it's standard, but I wouldn't know how to do it.

Comment: @LSpice Write $G$ as closed $\mathbf{Q}$-subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_n$. Write $U_1,U_2$ the two given unipotent subgroups, and write $U=U_1\cup U_2$ (it's not a subgroup). Let $G$ resp $U$ be the zero set of $P_G$, where $P_G$ resp $P_U$ is a tuple of polynomials. Suppose by contradiction for every $N$ there exists a field of char zero $k_N$ such that some element of $G(k_N)$ is not product of $N$ elements of $U(k_N)$. This can be written as 1st-order formula: $k_N$ satisfies the formula $F_N$: $\exists x: P_G(x)=0,\forall x_1,\dots x_N$ with $P_U(x_i)$, we have $x\neq x_1\dots x_N$. (...)

Comment: (...) fix a nonprincipal ultraproduct $k$ of the $k_N$. For each $n$, eventually $k_N$ satisfies $F_n$. So $k$ satisfies $F_n$. So bounded generation fails for $k$, contradiction. By the way if bounded generation holds in every field (not only char zero) then provided $G$ can be written uniformly over the field then the argument works in every char. Already, automatically $G$ is defined uniformly only removing finitely many small characteristics.

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430665/bounded-generation-of-group-by-unipotent-radicals-of-opposite-parabolic-subgroup/430666#comment1108249_430665), thanks!  Though you say that argument is standard, it is perhaps still worth writing as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope you will permit me to write $P^+$ in place of $P$.  Put $U^\pm = R_u(P^\pm)$.

Yes, at least in the split case.

Suppose first that $P^+$ and $P^-$ are minimal.  Put $T = P \cap P^-$.  By working in $\operatorname{SL}_2(k)$ or $\operatorname{PGL}_2(k)$, you see that, for all $t \in k^\times$ and all roots $\alpha$ of $T$ in $G$, you can write $\alpha^\vee(t)$ as a product of $6$ elements of $U^+(k)$ and $U^-(k)$.  This covers $T(k)$, using $6r$ elements, where $r$ is the semisimple rank of the group. Once you have written, for each element $w$ of the (finite!) Weyl group of $T$ in $G$, a representative of $w$ as a product of elements of $U^+(k)$ and $U^-(k)$ (which, again by a rank-$1$ computation, can be done using at most $3\ell$ elements, where $\ell$ is the length of a minimal expression for $w$ as a product of reflections), you only need $2$ more elements to generate the corresponding Bruhat cell.

Now continue to suppose that $G$ is split, but drop the assumption that $P^+$ and $P^-$ are minimal.  Put $M = P^+ \cap P^-$, and let $T$ be a split maximal torus in $M$.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $T$ in $M$.  Since we (should) have assumed that $P^+$ does not contain any isotropic factor of $G$, there is some root $\beta$ of $T$ in $U^+$ such that $\alpha + \beta$ is also a root of $T$ in $U^+$.  Then, for a suitable Chevalley–Steinberg system $(u_r : \operatorname{Add} \to U_r)_{\text{$r$ a root}}$, we have for all $t \in k$ that $[u_{-\beta}(t), u_{\alpha + \beta}(1)]$ lies in $u_\alpha(t)U^-(k)$.  That is, each element of $U_\alpha(k)$ is a product of $4$ elements of $U_{-\beta}(k) \subseteq U^-(k)$ and $U_{\alpha + \beta}(k) \subseteq U^+(k)$ with an element of $U^-(k)$.

This shows that the group of $k$-rational points of every root subgroup of $M$ is boundedly generated by $U^+(k)$ and $U^-(k)$; so, if $B_M^\pm$ are opposite Borel subgroups of $M$ containing $T$, then $R_u(B_M^\pm)(k)$ are boundedly generated by $U^+(k)$ and $U^-(k)$; so $R_u(B_M^\pm)(k)U^\pm(k) = R_u(B_M^\pm\cdot U^\pm)(k)$ is boundedly generated by $U^+(k)$ and $U^-(k)$.  Since $B_M^+\cdot U^+$ and $B_M^-\cdot U^-$ are opposite Borel subgroups of $G$, we have reduced to the previous case.

Comment: Good answer! I have no idea, but is it possible that there's a sort of "purely Coxeter-group" reason for this? My own perception of the physical/mechanical causality is certainly in line with this answer, but it would be interesting if there were "yet another" reason for this working out. Perhaps the role of the little $SL(2)$'s is an indirect expression of something that _could_ be said more abstractly?

Comment: @paulgarrett, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1108195), I wouldn't know where to begin in giving a purely Coxeter-group-theoretic explanation of a fact about semisimple groups—I don't even know how the Coxeter group would "see" the unipotent radical of a parabolic subgroup; the closest I can come is observing that one can very crudely bound the length of a minimal expression for a representative of a Weyl-group element by $3\ell$, where $\ell$ is its minimal length as a product of reflections.  However, I'd love to see whatever you come up with!

Comment: @LSpice: Hi, thanks for the answer. So basically, we first boundedly generate the maximal split torus $T$. Since the Weyl group is finite, these representatives too can be generated boundedly. And to generate the Bruhat cell, we use the Levy decomposition of $P$ (product of $T$ and $R_u(P)$). 
Does all of this also go through for non-minimal parabolics?

Comment: @BharatRam, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430665/bounded-generation-of-group-by-unipotent-radicals-of-opposite-parabolic-subgroup/430666#comment1108658_430666), to run the same argument, you'd need to replace the covering of the split maximal torus by a covering of a Levi component.  I don't immediately see how to do that.  In fact, I don't even immediately see how to handle minimal parabolics in the quasi-split but not split case, though I'm more confident that can be made to work.

Comment: @BharatRam, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430665/bounded-generation-of-group-by-unipotent-radicals-of-opposite-parabolic-subgroup/430666#comment1108658_430666), I still don't know how to handle the non-split case, but I have added an argument that I think covers the split but not-minimal case.

Comment: @LSpice: Thanks for the update. Btw, this might be trivial, but I don't follow the last lines. You say $R_u(B_M^{\pm})(k)$ is boundedly generated by $U^{+}$ and $U^{-}$. Doesn't this itself reduce to the earlier (minimal parabolic) case? Whats the need for further saying $R_u(B_M^{\pm})(k)U^{\pm}=R_u(B_M^{\pm}U^{\pm})(k)$ and $B_M^{\pm}U^{\pm}$ are opposite Borel subgroups?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430665/bounded-generation-of-group-by-unipotent-radicals-of-opposite-parabolic-subgroup/430666#comment1109645_430666), since $R_u(B_M^\pm)(k)$ are boundedly generated by $U^+(k)$ and $U^-(k)$, so is $M(k)$.  I could work from there *analogously to* my prior reasoning, with $M$ playing the role of $T$ in the minimal parabolic case; but, instead, I reduce *directly* to the minimal-parabolic case by producing opposite minimal subgroups $B_M^\pm\cdot U^\pm$ of $G$.  Or do I misunderstand your argument?

Comment: @LSpice: What I meant is that $R_u(B_M^{\pm})(k)$ are boundedly generated by $U^{\pm}$. And from the earlier part, $G(k)$ is boundedly generated by $R_u(B_M^{\pm})(k)$, and so $G(k)$ is boundedly generated by $U^{\pm}$. That is, arent $B_M^{\pm}$ themselves opposite minimal parabolics? Or am I confusing something?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430665/bounded-generation-of-group-by-unipotent-radicals-of-opposite-parabolic-subgroup/430666#comment1109658_430666), $B_M^\pm$ don't generate $G(k)$, boundedly or otherwise, since they're contained in $M(k)$.  (Instead, they boundedly generate $M(k)$.)  To get bounded generation of $G(k)$ using the prior argument, you need opposite minimal parabolics of $G$, and $B_M^+\cdot U^+$ and $B_M^-\cdot U^-$ are the natural candidates.

Comment: @LSpice: Ah yes, I got confused. By the way, another person I spoke to on this suggested another argument. Start with generation of $G(k)$ by $R_u(P^{\pm})$ to write a product map of sufficiently many $R_u(P^{\pm})$ to $G$, which is a dominant map, and so is an isomorphism on some open subset of $G$, meaning an open subset of $G$ is boundedly generated by $R_u(P^{\pm})$. Now using the Weyl group argument to get that a split torus is boundedly generated. We can combine the two to get the group $G$ is boundedly generated. At least, this is what I gathered, I don't fully understand the argument.

Comment: @BharatRam, yes, [such](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1109665) an argument, if I understand correctly, appears in [Borel - Linear algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-0941-6), Proposition 2.2, but it seems to me to work only on the level of varieties, or perhaps of $\overline k$-points; it is not obvious to me how to make it work for $k$-points. (I'm not sure what you mean by "using the Weyl group argument to get that a split torus is boundedly generated", so maybe I misunderstood.) But feel free to write up and accept that answer if it makes more sense to you!